# [ Flutter :: notched FloatingActionButton weird issue ]

Tags: flutter

Well this weird bug seems to have appeared when i recently updated flutter and dart sdk via my android studio IDE.

It worked like a charm before...

here what happens :

[this is what is expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59hDG.png)

[this is what i can have before a rebuild sometimes there is no notch at all...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yrnK.png)

So, to put words on the problem, the first picture is what i got so far and what i expect to have...

but recently, i did upgrade flutter N dart via the command line and had to face this weird bug...

Depending on the device here what i have :

- first build of the screen : incomplete notch margin or even none at all !
- when i do interact with a button or whatever provoke a screen rebuild : the notch is good again !

For example, the 2 screenshots come from the exact same screen, nothing changed but an only checkbox checked forcing the screen to rebuild after dirty state...

The problem is that i can't see anything to do since the code is as simple as :

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
...
floatingActionButtonLocation: 
FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
        height: 85.0,
        width: 85.0,
        child: FittedBox(
          child: FloatingActionButton(
```

So, is it a known Flutter bug and just have to wait for a bugFix ?
Or can i do something and, if so, what ?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue trying to change the page with the navigator and rebuilding one page that has the same bottom app bar with this notch, I think that there is some bug between the fab notch and the navigator.
The workaround in my case is to keep the same route for all the pages and manage more pages changing the widget structure with the state, so if you have 3 pages with this notch you can keep the same page route and change one big sub-widget for each page changing, for example, a state variable that keeps the page like an int that encode one page with a specific number, and when you update this variable the interface rebuild changing this page widget.
This is my workaround, hope that this bug could be solved early but meanwhile this work.

Some images of the bug:

- I have this rendering behavior after the first app start and after each rebuild on the same page, note that I have the fab notch in my homepage so at the first start the rendering is good:

[image]

- I have this behavior after each change of route page with all the Navigator methods, even if in the page the bottom app bar has the same configuration and should render the notch:

[image]

If could help someone I recreate the navigator with an inherited widget and a stateful widget on top of the widget tree, this approach gets around the bug, here is my app implementation:
https://github.com/simone-viozzi/progetto-programmazione-mobile/tree/main/flutter_app

Comment: I think i don't understand your workaround :s
In my case i have an only screen that has this notched button and on first appearance it's not good...
i have to wait a first rebuild to see the notched correctly...
so what do you advice me to do ?

Comment: When you open the first time the app, is the fab (with or without the bug) present on your home page, or does it appears on another page? 
In my case, it is on the home page, and when the app starts the first time it is correctly rendered and the problem starts when I try to change page with the Navigator.
If you have the problem with the first start of the app without calling the navigator my workaround doesn't work in your case I'm sorry.